# How to delete area of polygons that overlap?

Tags: polygon, qgis

I am trying to take a single layer of polygon buffers and delete the areas in which these circular buffers overlap (or intersect... I am not sure about the correct terminology here). I have so far tried the `Intersection` tool and `Symmetrical difference` tool, but these requires two layer inputs, and I am just working with a single layer. How can I accomplish this? I am working in QGIS.

Here is what I am working with:
[image]

I simply want to select and delete the areas where these circles overlap. I have searched this extensively online, but cannot find a solution that works for me, since I am only working with one layer.

Comment: I think you'll need to write a custom processing tool that examines overlapping polygons and deletes the overlap one at a time

Answer (score 1):

You can perform SQL Query with `Execute SQL` tool [
[https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#id85](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgisexecutesql)]

Where Additional input datasources is your circle layer, that must have unique value, in my example attribute is called `fid`

Query is:

```
select c1.fid as fid1, c2.fid as fid2, intersection(c1.geometry,c2.geometry) as geometry
from input1 as c1, input1 as c2
where c1.fid > c2.fid and st_intersects(c1.geometry,c2.geometry)
```

[image: Execute SQL tool]

query result is intersaction between geometries:
[image: intersaction between geometries]

aftert that you can do  [`symmetrical difference`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/it/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#qgissymmetricaldifference) to optain

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can try select by location analysis, if select "Where the feature" condition "Overlap", it select just overlap features.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Au5eK.png)

And delete after.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new QGis plugin named "Buffer Without Overlaps" that works fine!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31425642)